# RuntimeError: The array return by func must be one-dimensional, but got ndim=2

Tags: python

I am trying to solve an MDF system, using python odeint macro from scipy.integrate.

Here is my code

```
import pylab
from scipy.integrate import odeint

"""
Définition des paramétres
"""
m1 = 100
m2 = 75
m3 = 50
k1 = 1e4
k2 = 5e4
k3 = 3e4
F0 = 100
xi = 0.03
V0 = 1

def eqmvt(t,x, M, K, C, F):
    D = block([[zeros((3,3)), eye(3)],[-dot(inv(M),K), -dot(inv(M),C)]])
    Dr = D*x + block([[zeros((3,1))],[dot(inv(M),F)]])
    return Dr

M=diag([m1,m2,m3])

K=array([[k1+k2, -k2, 0],
         [-k2, k2+k3, -k3],
         [0,-k3, k3]])

C=diag([2*m1*xi,2*m2*xi,2*m3*xi])

t=linspace(0,3.4,350)

om=45

F=F0*array([[0],[1],[0]]) # *sin(om*t)

eVal, Vect=eig(inv(K)*M)

u0=[0.2,.43,0.8,1.2,1.6,0.2]

U=odeint(eqmvt,u0,t, args=(M, K, C, F))

plot(t,U[:,0:3])
```

When I run the code I get an error message.

```
 File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\odepack.py", 
 line 244, in odeint
 int(bool(tfirst)))

 RuntimeError: The array return by func must be one-dimensional, but got 
 ndim=2.
```

Normally with a two degrees of freedom it works fine. But I tried to make it three degrees, and to my surprise it does not work anymore.

Does any one have a clue ? I read similar posts but they don't solve the problem.

Comment: It is a very bad idea to have a half dozen or more variables that have one or two letter names. You should consider writing self-documenting variable names such as, "surface_area" instead of "a". 
Why do you have a large number of floating point numbers, each with a short name such as m1, m2, m3
k1, k2, k3, F0, xi ?

Comment: If you are going to re-use the same set of numbers over and over again, I reccomend writing a class and storing those numbers as member variables of the class.

Comment: I wanted to use this code in all 3 degrees of freedom models.